# Cannot resolve symbol 'gms'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I'm attempting to follow the instruction on how to code the AdMob into my app and I stumbled on `Cannot resolve symbol 'gms'` import. any clue on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your `build.gradle` have you `import com.google.android.gms.ad` ? for more information please check [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary)

Comment: I follow Google's instructions step by step, this is what they say should go to the build.gradle '** implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0' ** which I did. is there anything els that I need to do which they didn't say I should? @Aldan